# React React-Hooks useEffect dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

if a function that never change ( it is pure ) should it go inside the dependency array ?

let say this is my child component :

```
function ChildComponent({onChange}) {
    const [state, setState] = useState('state')

    useEffect(() => {
    onChange(state)
    }, [state])

    return <h1 onClick={_ => setState('newState')}> something </h1>
}
```

and this is my Parent component that uses the child

```
function ParentComponent({addressItems}) {
    const setSomething = something => {
       // push something in browser address bar
       // this cause a reRender in Parent Component because in a higher level we pass the addressItems to ParentComponent as props 
    }

    const handleNameChange = name => {
      setSomething(name)
    }

    return <> <ChildComponent onChange={hanldeNameChange}/> </>

}
```

this is what do i mean

and note that every time that onChange function runs it cause a reRender in parent component

i have changed this code and move it to the event handler and it works fine but the react.dev docs says that everything that is inside the useEffect should go into the dependency array is this an exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how complete this answer is but I'll give my understanding.
Everything that is used in the effect should strictly speaking be in the dependency array. React does not know whether it will change or not so requires that all variables be in the array. And if it does not change it will not trigger the effect.

In your case, and I think this happens often, you will probably get an infinite run of the effect if you add it to deps.

```
Child state changes -> effect runs -> callback runs -> callback changes parent -> 
parent rerenders -> new reference for function -> deps changes by reference -> use effect triggers ...
```

So the issue is dependencies are compared by reference and if the parent rerenders then the callback has a new reference.
I think its possible if the parent rerender is dependant on the child state actually changing that this will not be an issue.

If it is, you can either omit the callback from the deps and rely on the fact you know it does not change, or in the parent component, you can use `useCallback` to ensure the function keeps the same reference between rerenders.

Comment: exactly what you said is happening and   and as i said i changed the structure and  there is no useEffect any more and just want to share this to talk about  this with community   thank you buddy .

Comment: yeaa nice, happy it works well for this